# Подключение event к GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня имеется некий gameobject внутри которого находятся несколько спрайтов. мне надо сделать этот gameobject кликабельным (при клике идет вызов функции с параметрами).

```
  buttons.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => load_level(level_name_, location_name_));
```

Как запилить подобную запись только для gm,

ибо такая запись:

```
  buttons.GetComponent<EventTrigger>().OnPointerEnter(() => load_level(level_name_, location_name_));
```

не работает

Upd:

У меня имется массив gameobject и list c набором данных разнящихся для каждого gameobject, в цикле я передаю эти данные в gameobjectы.
Поэтому мне необходимо привязать вызов функции с параметрами из lista сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первый способ:** 
(Если вы все таки хотите своим методом)

```
void Start()
    {
        EventTrigger pointerHoverTrigger = buttons.GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
        EventTrigger.Entry yourNewEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        yourNewEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick; 
        pointerHoverTrigger.triggers.Add(yourNewEntry);

        yourNewEntry.callback.AddListener((eventData) =>
           {
         //...
         print("Нажата ЛКМ");
           });
    }
```

**Второй способ**: (Если вам надо отлавливать нажатия кнопок мыши (используя метод OnMouseOver))

1. Добавляете коллайдер к объекту. Это будет та область, на которую вам необходимо будет кликнуть.
2. Добавляете метод `void OnMouseOver()`
3. Проверяете нажатие на объект: `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))` // 0 - ЛКМ, 1 - ПКМ, 2- СКМ.

Т.е. должен получится следующий код:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Нажата ЛКМ");
    }
}
```

Comment: По первому пункту: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Не пойму почему. загуглил по строке на ответах unity такой же пример и всё пашет...

Comment: @Slimper Что-то, наверное, с ссылкой. Проверьте, действительно ли вы обращаетесь к тому GO'у. И висит ли на на GO'е `EventTrigger`.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ это добавить к GameObject-у коллайдер и реализовывать методы MonoBehaviour-а OnMouseDown, OnMouseDrag, OnMouseEnter, OnMouseExit, OnMouseOver, OnMouseUp

```
public class Hello : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown(){
        Debug.Log("Mouse click catched!");
    }
}
```